# Javascript recursive Item Remove doesnt work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a array of json like that:

and this is my code to remove a specific item with all of its childs sub childs ...:

```js
     const items = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: true,  parent_id : null},
      {id: 2, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: true,  parent_id : 1},
      {id: 3, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: false,  parent_id : 1},
      {id: 4, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: true,  parent_id : 2},
      {id: 5, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: false,  parent_id : 2},
      {id: 6, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: false,  parent_id : 2},
      {id: 7, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: false,  parent_id : 4}
    ];
    
    function removeItem(item){
                    var index = items.findIndex(function (o) {
                        return o.id == item.id;
                    })
    
                    if (index !== -1) {
    
                        var hasOtherChilds = false;
                        items.forEach((i) => {
                            if(i.parent_id == item.parent_id)
                                hasOtherChilds = true;
                        });
    
                        
                        items.forEach((i)=> {
                            if(i.id == item.parent_id && !hasOtherChilds)
                                i.has_childs  = false;
                        } )
                        
                        if (items[index].has_childs == true) {
                            var items_to_remove = [];
                            items.forEach((i) => {
                                if (i.parent_id == item.id) {
                                    items.splice(index, 1);
                                    items_to_remove.push(i);
                                }
                            });
    
                        }else {
                           items.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                    }
    
                    if(items_to_remove)
                    items_to_remove.forEach((item) => {
                        removeItem(item);
                    });
        }
    
    
    console.log(items);
    
    removeItem(items[1]);
    
    console.log(items)
```

But for some reason, he is always only deleting the first child/subchild and the last child/subchild i have no idea why

Comment: But no object in your data structure has any "childs" (children)?

Comment: @JeremyThille I think the `parent_id` defines the parent node for children.

Comment: Aaaah, ok I get it now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the IDs to remove in array.
So in each iteration in filter we check

if the `id` exists in array, if it does exist then we return false.
if it does not exists then we check, if `parentId` exists in array, if it does then we push the `id` in array and return false. at last if both of above conditions are failed then we return true.

Check following snippet.

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Block',
    text: '',
    has_childs: true,
    parent_id: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Block',
    text: '',
    has_childs: true,
    parent_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Block',
    text: '',
    has_childs: true,
    parent_id: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Block',
    text: '',
    has_childs: true,
    parent_id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Block',
    text: '',
    has_childs: false,
    parent_id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Block',
    text: '',
    has_childs: false,
    parent_id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Block',
    text: '',
    has_childs: false,
    parent_id: 4
  }
];

function remove(arr, id) {
  const idToRemove = [id];
  return items
    .filter((item) => {
      if (idToRemove.includes(item.id))
        return false;
      if (idToRemove.includes(item.parent_id)) {
        idToRemove.push(item.id);
        return false;
      } else return true;
    });
}

const filteredItems = remove(items, 1);

filteredItems.forEach(item => console.log(item)); //verify the right ones are gone
```

Here is more on [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Performance wise, should use a set or {} for faster lookups, instead of iterating through the array each time with .includes(). See the example with new Set() below.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not have a simple function to just filter out the values? Based on the structure of the array you want to filter (it isn't nested), I don't see any need for recursion.

```
const items = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: true,  parent_id : null},
  {id: 2, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: true,  parent_id : 1},
  {id: 3, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: true,  parent_id : 1},
  {id: 4, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: true,  parent_id : 2},
  {id: 5, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: false,  parent_id : 2},
  {id: 6, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: false,  parent_id : 2},
  {id: 7, name: 'Block', text: '', has_childs: false,  parent_id : 4}
];

function remove(arr, id) {    
    const removed = new Set([id]);

    return arr.filter(item => {
      if (removed.has(item.parent_id)) {
          removed.add(item.id);
          return false;
      }
      
      return !removed.has(item.id);
    });
}

//suppose we want to remove id = 2 and all its progeny
const filteredItems = remove(items, 2);

filteredItems.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Comment: yes but there the subchilds doesnt get removed, (the childs of the childs of the object with the id 1

Comment: I've added that functionality. Still don't need recursion.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that recursively deletes all children, then the original item itself.
Note that the `has_childs` property is completely useless in this process.

```js
let items = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Block', text: '', parent_id : null},
  {id: 2, name: 'Block', text: '', parent_id : 1},
  {id: 3, name: 'Block', text: '', parent_id : 1},
  {id: 4, name: 'Block', text: '', parent_id : 2},
  {id: 5, name: 'Block', text: '', parent_id : 2},
  {id: 6, name: 'Block', text: '', parent_id : 2},
  {id: 7, name: 'Block', text: '', parent_id : 4}
];

const removeItem = item => {

    // Selecting all children
    const children = items.filter(i => i.parent_id===item.id);

    for(let child of children){
        console.log(`Removing child ${child.id}`)
        removeItem(child) // Will recursively remove all of their children
    }

    // Removing the original item itself, after removing all its children recursively
    items = items.filter(i => i.id !== item.id)
}

removeItem({id: 2, name: 'Block', text: '', parent_id : 1})

console.log("Items are now =", items)
```